# Data file not found

Tags: react-native, ocr, tesseract

I am making react native app with tesseract ocr. When I add image using react native image picker our gives me error:

> OCR Error:  [Error: Data file not found at /storage/emulated/0/com.textrecognition/tessdata/eng.traineddata]

But I have created folder assets/tessdata in android/app/src/main/assets/tessdata and there I put my file, what am I doing wrong?